# Unable to open Keychain Access on Mac

Tags: macos, keychain

When I try to open Keychain Access using Spotlight or Finder, I see an error saying: The Application "Keychain Access" is not open anymore. When I try to launch using open -a, I get:

```
$ open -a Keychain\ Access.app/
Unable to find application named 'Keychain Access.app/'
```

It was working fine until yesterday. A restart did not seem to help.

[image: Screenshot of image showing the Finder error message]

**Update**:

It looks like I shouldn't rely on Terminal's autocomplete while using open. Removing the trailing slash did not fix it. The new error is:

```
$ open -a Keychain\ Access.app
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app with error -600.
```

**Update 2**:

Somehow it got fixed on its own. Among the things I tried was a restart, opening the app via the Terminal, and removing the plist from ~/Library/Preferences. None of those seemed to have had an immediate effect, if any at all, but Keychain Access is finally opening for me.

Comment: error -600 means **no eligible process with specified descriptor** maybe keychain app is corrupt? Have you an earlier version (from backup for example?)

Comment: Unfortunately, Time Machine was not enabled on my machine.

Comment: I think the problem isn't your keychain itself but corrupt files. Try to boot into Internet Recovery **CMD + Option + R**  open disk utility and try to repair your drive. If doesn't work you need to reinstall maOS. Download from App Store and install - update current system does not affect of your personally data.

Answer (score 1):

Lose the /.

```
$ open -a Keychain\ Access.app
```

works for me.
Or even:

> $ open -a Keychain\ Access

Answer (score 0):

Note: no "/" at the end - works perfectly fine for me too.

```
$ open -a Keychain\ Access
```

Terminal must have been reading it as part of the fine name or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Copy `com.apple.keychainaccess.plist` from here: `/Users/YourName/Library/Preferences` to some safe place and then delete it from the original location. Then try to launch Keychain Access again.

Comment: Already tried that. Did not help. :(